# Template name does not take effect

Tags: 7, theming, caching

I got a field with xyz as machine name, and I created a field--field-xyz.tpl.php template file, but it does not take any effect.
I used the template file to add views-field and views-field-field-xyz as CSS classes, but they don't show up.

What did I do wrong?
Is it because I am using the Adaptive theme?

Comment: Have you tried clearing cache etc.?

Comment: yes, i cleared it.

Comment: Where did you place the template file ? Is your base theme set correctly ?

Comment: @Wtower. The solution is, not just clearing the cache.
You also have to flush theme caching.
https://drupal.org/node/337176

How lovely it is .. spending hours for a solution like this. Great! 

Can't actually answer my own question..

Comment: Sorry, can't get the difference...

Comment: Cleaning Cache on /admin/config/development/performance/ is not enough. I flushed it via Views, maybe it is just a Views 3 problem?

Comment: Again I cannot understand. When you clear cache properly then all cache tables all cleared including views.

Answer (score 0):

Does xyz field name contain underscores?

> Note that underscores in a Field's machine name are replaced by
>   hyphens. Also remember to include "field-" in custom field names, e.g:
>   field--field-phone.tpl.php.

https://drupal.org/node/1089656

EDIT:
Add a `hook_preprocess_field(&$vars)` in your theme and dpm($vars) to check up on theme_hook_suggestions array for this field.

Comment: Thx, but that is not the solution, i know the suggestions. i am really frustrated. this should be a piece of cake.